# How to display class attributes for a class object initialized in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a class Employee in a WPF Project:

```
class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I am creating an instance of it `emp2` in my XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Employee x:Key="emp2" ID="20" Name="Second Employee "></local:Employee>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>        
        <Label x:Name="lblEmpInfo2" FontSize="18" Margin="20" Content="{StaticResource emp2}"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

However this only displays the datatype of `emp2` i.e. `WpfApplication1.Employee`. How do I display the ID and Name of `emp2`

Comment: Try emp2.ID, emp2.Name

Comment: It says `The resource emp2.ID could not be resolved`

Comment: have you checked it runtime ?

Comment: It doesn't run as there is an error in the XAML file which throws an XMLParseException if we try to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF uses the concept of `DataTemplates` to give you the possibility to decide how data objects should be presented. Therefore you could define a `DataTemplate` for the class `Employee` and then use a `ContentControl` which uses the instance of the `Employee` class as its `Content`. The `DataTemplate` could contain controls to show the values.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:Employee x:Key="emp2" ID="20" Name="Second Employee "></local:Employee>
    <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type local:Employee}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding ID} />
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource emp2}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: You're welcome. You could use <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> or have a look at the control <Grid>

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<Label x:Name="lblEmpInfo2" FontSize="18" Margin="20" Content="{Binding Path=Name, Source={StaticResource emp2}}"></Label>
```

Or implement the `ToString` method override of the `Employee` class

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0} {1}", Id, Name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your binding's just a wee bit off:

```
<Label x:Name="lblEmpInfo2" FontSize="18" Margin="20" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource emp2}, Path=ID}"></Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options:

1. Use DataTemplates (MatthiasG's answer)
2. Quick and dirty: Implement ToString() in class Employee, simple but not very flexible.
3. Use StaticResource as Binding Source:

   ```
   <StackPanel>
     <Label Content="{Binding ID, Source={StaticResource emp2}}"></Label>
     <Label Content="{Binding Name, Source={StaticResource emp2}}"></Label>
   </StackPanel>
   ```